# How can i retrieve the specified value from the Map field of MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document with an Map field `metaMap`, similar to this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "....",
  "metaMap" : {
     "k1":{
         'ka':'va',
      },
     "k2":{
         'kb':'vb',
      },
     //...
  }
}
```

How can I build the query and projection to retrieve the value of `metaMap` specified by a key ?

For example,when query with param `k2`,the following partial document will returned:

```
{
 'kb':'vb',
}
```

Comment: try this: `db.collection.find({}, {"metaMap.k2": 1})`

Comment: Well basically in the same way you "wrote it",  `"metaMap.k2.kb"` which is what your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44301887/2313887) was about.

Comment: yes,I figured it out.thanks